# Most Robust Data Source for Production Environment

Tags: spring, datasource, connection-pooling

I was using `DriverManagerDataSource` for local development. I am currently using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` now because too many connections were being created.

Does anyone have suggestions on what the best way to go about setting up database in production for client is in terms of connection pools?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a t [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/), it is quite fast.

Besides all the examples, there is [FAQ](http://jolbox.com/faq.html) that would give you a very concise and nice overview of connection pooling, corner cases, and how BoneCP handles them.

Answer (score 0):

I usually tend to go for [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). It's always worked out fine for me. Haven't actually done any deeper analysis or comparisons since C3P0 has always been "good enough" in terms of performance and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,I strongly recommend using pooled data sources for Production ready applications.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
```

`DriverManagerDataSource` nor `Single-ConnectionDataSource` provides a connection pool, there are no pool configuration properties to set.

Although `SingleConnectionDataSource` and `DriverManagerDataSource` are great
for small applications and running in development, you should seriously consider the implications of using either in a production application. Because `SingleConnection-DataSource` has one and only one database connection to work with, it doesn’t work well in a multithreaded application. At the same time, even though `DriverManager-DataSource` is capable of supporting multiple threads, **it incurs a performance cost for creating a new connection each time a connection is requested**. Because of these limitations, I strongly recommend using pooled data sources.

I've shown sample Pooled DataSource configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<propertyname="driverClassName"value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
<propertyname="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/test"/>
<propertyname="username"value="sa"/>
<propertyname="password"value=""/>
<propertyname="initialSize"value="5"/>
<propertyname="maxActive"value="10"/>
</bean>
```